# Cache Control for Dynamic Data Express.JS

Tags: node.js, caching, express

How it is possible to set up a **cache-control** policy in **express.js** on JSON response?

My JSON response doesn't change at all, so I want to cache it aggressively.

I found how to do caching on static files but can't find how to make it on dynamic data.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The inelegant way is to simply add a call to `res.set()` prior to any JSON output. There, you can specify to set the cache control header and it will cache accordingly.

```
res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=31557600'); // one year
```

Another approach is to simply set a `res` property to your JSON response in a route then use fallback middleware (prior to the error handling) to render and send the JSON.

```
app.get('/something.json', function (req, res, next) {
  res.JSONResponse = { 'hello': 'world' };
  next(); // important! 
});

// ...

// Before your error handling middleware:

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (! ('JSONResponse' in res) ) {
    return next();
  }

  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=31557600');
  res.json(res.JSONResponse);
})
```

Edit: Changed from `res.setHeader` to `res.set` for Express v4

Comment: isn't it `res.header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=31557600')` ?

Comment: Be carefull, in Express 4.x, you have to use `res.set({ headers })` or `res.header({ headers })` instead of `res.setHeader({ headers })` as [it is now documented](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.set).

Comment: don't forget about `immutable` http://bitsup.blogspot.com/2016/05/cache-control-immutable.html

Comment: This didn't worked for me. I had posted similar question and still awaiting an answer. Can anyone help me with this ? Question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700579/setting-cache-control-pubic-not-caching-xhr

Comment: what does the `public` in the header do?

Comment: The public response directive indicates that a resource can be cached by any cache. It's not client specific.

Comment: How to delete the public cache, using api response. I tried cache-control: no-cache, no-store but not working.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this, for example :

```
res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=31557600, s-maxage=31557600'); // 1 year
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question recently, what worked for me was to do the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
let options = {
  maxAge: '2y',
  etag: false
}

app.use(express.static('public', options));
```

Basically with `maxAge` you set your cache time.
Documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html