# How to set cache policy for specific resource file

Tags: browser-cache, cache-control

All:

I am pretty new to Cache Control, I wonder how can I set cache policy for specific resource file.

Like:

I want to cache only JS file and image, but not css file(currently I am using Express.js and Chrome). A concrete example is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cache Control for Dynamic Data Express.JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462717/cache-control-for-dynamic-data-express-js)

Comment: @Joe Thanks, that helps, but one question about that is how do I determine the request is for a js file or image? suppose only JS and png and jpeg required(but they are located in many different folders)