# How to add Cache-control and ETag header in Angular 4 Universal?

Tags: express, caching, cache-control, etag, angular-universal

After running Google page speed test I got suggestion:

> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static
>   resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded
>   resources from local disk rather than over the network.

***server.ts***

```
//import statements   

enableProdMode();
const app = express();
const port = Number(process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: ServerAppModule
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

import {
  getHomeApi, sendMailApi
} from './backend/api';

app.get('/api/homeData', getHomeApi);
app.post("/api/send", sendMailApi);


app.use(compression());

app.use('',express.static('dist'));

app.use('/assets',express.static('dist/assets'));

app.use('/static',express.static('dist/static', {
  index: false
}));

ROUTES.forEach(route => {
  app.get(route, (req, res) => {
    console.time(`GET: ${req.originalUrl}`);
    res.render('../dist/index', {
      req: req,
      res: res
    });
    console.timeEnd(`GET: ${req.originalUrl}`);
  });
});

app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log(`Listening at ${port}`);
});
```

It suggested me to leverage caching for following static resources.

> http://00.000.00.00:8080/api/homeData (expiration not specified)
>
> http://dsms0mj1bbhn4.cloudfront.net/assets/pub/shareaholic.js
>   (10minutes)
>
> https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)

So how can I do this?
Thank You.

Comment: This is an Express question. Why is it tagged with `angular`?

Comment: @estus bcoz I'm trying to do it in Angular 4 Universal, you right though, `angular` tag can be removed

Comment: @estus do you have any idea, how to do it?

Comment: Yes, the mention of Universal is necessary, it provides the context for the question. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462717/cache-control-for-dynamic-data-express-js .